# Publishing Aspnet Core project to IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, asp.net-core, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have successfully generated a publish folder via following command;

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 --self-contained
```

[image]

Here is the generated exe file in publish folder.
If I run the exe file, the website runs with no problem on localhost:5000.

However; when I try to put this website on iis, I have the following error;

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
```

,

```
Error Code     0x8007000d
```

[image]

Here is my web config file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\AURORA.MvcWebUI.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>



<!--ProjectGuid: 1E855145-26EA-4E34-8527-9A44CCB14290-->
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: You missed the most important thing in the 500.19 error page. Which line number did it say?

Comment: solved it, thanks!

Comment: You might post the solution as an answer below and accept it.